# Cloudflare CDN doesnt work properly on Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, cdn, cloudflare

I set up to my wordpress website Cloudflare for CDN and security reasons.
Still all the content in my website comes from my domain. Everything looks fine. Changed the nameservers etc

When I inspect my elements all content is coming from mydomain.com/wp-content/blabla

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected. Since you actually setup your DNS records with CloudFlare, they serve resources from your domain. Resources should not come from CloudFlare's domain (even though they are being sent from CloudFlare servers). To verify that this is actually the case, the article below shows how to use webpagetest.org to verify that the cf-cache header is provided in the response.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169556-How-can-I-tell-if-Cloudflare-is-caching-my-site-or-a-specific-file-